# Can't upgrade packages Mint linux Vanessa (forbidden mirror)

Tags: networking, apt, apt-mirror

I want to install Play On Linux and I was trying to update and upgrade the packages before, but I'm having a problem, when I run the command

```
sudo apt update
```

then

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

here's what I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libsmbclient libwbclient0 python3-samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-libs
  smbclient xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-legacy
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnss-myhostname libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5
  libqt5widgets5 libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb mesa-va-drivers
  qt5-gtk-platformtheme
10 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 14.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libqt5core5a amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
Err:2 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libqt5dbus5 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
Err:3 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libqt5network5 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
Err:4 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libqt5gui5 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
Err:5 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libqt5widgets5 amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
Err:6 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libreoffice-base-drivers amd64 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
Err:7 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb amd64 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
Err:8 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 mesa-va-drivers amd64 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
Err:9 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 qt5-gtk-platformtheme amd64 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
Err:10 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 libnss-myhostname amd64 249.11-0ubuntu3.6
  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]   
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5core5a_5.15.3%2bdfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5dbus5_5.15.3%2bdfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5network5_5.15.3%2bdfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5gui5_5.15.3%2bdfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5widgets5_5.15.3%2bdfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu/pool/universe/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-base-drivers_7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu/pool/universe/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb_7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mesa/mesa-va-drivers_22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qtbase-opensource-src/qt5-gtk-platformtheme_5.15.3%2bdfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/systemd/libnss-myhostname_249.11-0ubuntu3.6_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 196.200.160.70 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have tried `apt-get update --fix-missing`

and here's what it shows

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
Ign:1 https://mirror.airenetworks.es/linuxmint/packages vanessa InRelease                                                    
Hit:2 https://mirror.airenetworks.es/linuxmint/packages vanessa Release                                                      
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease       
Hit:5 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy InRelease     
Get:6 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:7 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Get:8 http://mirror.marwan.ma/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [11.4 kB]
Fetched 225 kB in 6s (37.7 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
```

when I run the command `sudo apt upgrade` again nothing changes, I tried to install Play On Linux anyways using the command

```
sudo apt install playonlinux
```

but it didn't work, what do you thing the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

> There is not even tiny bit of evidence that the Forbidden lines are to be remedied by aptitude. Simply change mirror, as this one is not working at the moment. That's all there is to it.

---

> How can I make a proper choice of the mirror?

---

The answer is actually very simple, when it's not working, revert to the default ones. These official mirrors are more or less guaranteed to always work (use `mintsources`):

[image: default mirrors in Mint]